# ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: '[object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working with Reactive Forms and I'm trying to pass my form down to child components, but I'm running into the error above. Initially at the top level of the form I was using a FormArray to hold my form and that was working fine before I tried passing it down to the child components. Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288928/when-to-use-formgroup-vs-formarray) post I now know that the top level of a form should be a FormGroup and the FormArray should be a child of the FormGroup.

So now I am nesting my FormArray inside of a FormGroup and I'm getting the error above. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?  Below in the relevant code.

// Parent component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    if (!!this.rows) {

        this.tableForm = new FormArray([]);

        this.rows.forEach((row) => {
            this.rowGroup = new FormGroup({})
            this.columns.forEach(column => {
                this.rowGroup.addControl(column.key, new FormControl(row[column.key]));
            });
            this.tableForm.push(this.rowGroup);
        })

        this.tableGroup = new FormGroup({
            rows: new FormControl(this.tableForm)
        })
    }
}
```

// Parent HTML

```
<section
    *ngIf="!!modal"
    class="modal__mask">
    <section
        class="modal__container"
        #carousel
        [ngStyle]="{'left': start + 'px'}"
        (window:resize)="onResize($event)"
        [formGroup]="tableGroup">

        <div
            *ngFor='let row of selectedRows; let i = index'
            class="modal modal__large"
            [formArrayName]="rows">
            <div
                [formGroupName]="i"
                [ngClass]="{'opacity': modalPage !== i}">
                <div class="modal__header modal__header--large">
                    <h6>Edit Employee Details</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="u-flex u-wrap">
                    <div
                        class="u-flex modal__body"
                        style="width: 50%"
                        *ngFor="let column of columns">
                        <div
                            *ngIf="column.label"
                            class="input__wrapper"
                            [ngClass]="{'input__wrapper--inline': layout === 'horizontal'}">
                            <z-input
                                *ngIf="column.label"
                                class="u-maxX"
                                [group]="tableGroup"
                                [config]="column"> 
                            </z-input>

                            <!-- <div>
                                    <label
                                        class="input__label">
                                        <p class="t-bold t-data">{{column.label}}</p>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="z-input__default">
                                        <input
                                            class="input u-maxX"
                                         [formControlName]="column.key"
                                            [value]="row[column.key]">
                                    </div>
                                </div> -->

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <section class="modal__footer u-fillRemaining">
                        <div class="u-flex">
                            <button
                                class="button button--medium"
                                (click)="nextSelectedRow()">
                                <div class="button__content">
                                    <i
                                        class="icon icon--medium"
                                        *ngIf="!!icon">
                                        {{icon}}
                                    </i>
                                    <span>Skip</span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="u-flex">
                            <button
                                class="button button--low"
                                (click)="reset(row, i)">
                                <div class="button__content">
                                    <i
                                        class="icon icon--medium"
                                        *ngIf="!!icon">
                                        {{icon}}
                                    </i>
                                    <span>Reset</span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                            <button
                                class="button button--low"
                                (click)="saveChanges(row, i)">
                                <div class="button__content">
                                    <i
                                        class="icon icon--medium"
                                        *ngIf="!!icon">
                                        {{icon}}
                                    </i>
                                    <span>Save Changes</span>
                                </div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

// Child component.ts

```
@Input() config;
@Input() group: FormGroup;
@Input() view: string;
@Input() layout: string;
```

// Child HTML

```
<div
    class="input__wrapper"
    [ngClass]="{'input__wrapper--inline': layout === 'horizontal'}"
    [formGroup]="group"
    [ngSwitch]="config.type">
    <label
        class="input__label"
        *ngIf="!!config.label">
        <p class="t-bold t-data">{{config.label}}</p>
    </label>

    <z-select
        *ngSwitchCase="'select'"
        [config]="config"
        [group]="group"
        [view]="view"
        gridColumn="1 / 5">
    </z-select>

    <div class="z-input__default">
        <input
            *ngSwitchDefault
            class="input u-maxX"
            [formControlName]="config.key"
            [attr.type]="config.type"
            [attr.placeholder]="config.placeholder">
    </div>
```

Comment: Why use `(!!this.rows)` - instead of `(this.rows)`?

Comment: It's a safety check. It forces this.rows to be a boolean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284664/double-exclamation-points

Comment: Wouldn't you need each column in each row to be unique? When you say  `[config]="column"`  in **parent.html** that won't be unique. What exactly is the data type of config? I know at the moment it would equate to any... But what are you expecting - so you can reference things like `config.key` later  in **child.html**

Comment: The data type is an object. I pass the entire thing so I can reference it as needed in the child components.

Comment: And where exactly is the reference to the child component in the parent html -  in terms of the markup? What is it's name. I suspect that is the cause of your error!

Comment: It's called z-input

Comment: Have you looked at this example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/klboqnejrdd - wondered if anything in that would give some more clues. Also in the child component have you tried dumping out the values of those @Input variables. Perhaps with JSON.stringify() (console.log()) - perhaps add the output of that to the question, so we can see what was bound.